# I am getting error 1136 column count doesnt match valaue count at row 1 SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Hi I am getting error 1136 column count doesnt match valaue count at row 1, i have spent ages checking and double checking the data, commas etc and cant figure out for the life of me why im getting this error. This is my table and INSERT command:

```
 CREATE TABLE EDITORS (
Username VARCHAR(100),
EName VARCHAR(320),
Email VARCHAR(40),
DOB DATE,
blogTitle VARCHAR(80),
PRIMARY KEY (Username)

);

INSERT INTO EDITORS (Username,EName,Email,DOB,blogTitle) VALUES (
'john360','johnWest','jwest360@yahoo.co.uk','1980-08-23','MyGeneralBlog',
'paul22344','paulWells','psmith@yahoo.co.uk','1960-09-20','PaulsBlog',
'chrisB123','chrisBenson','cb360@hotmail.co.uk','1990-10-14','MyBlog'
);
```

any help at all will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: You have 5 columns and 15 values, I'd call that a mismatch. The error message didn't lie. Either remove 10 of them or split them up into 3 sets of bracketed values.

Comment: Read the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html - `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);` - After what Google said with "insert mysql".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must split your data into rows like that:

```
INSERT INTO EDITORS (Username,EName,Email,DOB,blogTitle) VALUES 
('john360','johnWest','jwest360@yahoo.co.uk','1980-08-23','MyGeneralBlog'),
('paul22344','paulWells','psmith@yahoo.co.uk','1960-09-20','PaulsBlog'),
('chrisB123','chrisBenson','cb360@hotmail.co.uk','1990-10-14','MyBlog');
```

Comment: Thanks so much, just saved me even more wasted time

Answer (score 1):

Your Syntax For Inserting Multiple Records is Wrong

You can Use:

**Single Statement**

```
INSERT INTO EDITORS (Username,EName,Email,DOB,blogTitle)
 VALUES 
('john360','johnWest','jwest360@yahoo.co.uk','1980-08-23','MyGeneralBlog'),
('paul22344','paulWells','psmith@yahoo.co.uk','1960-09-20','PaulsBlog'),
('chrisB123','chrisBenson','cb360@hotmail.co.uk','1990-10-14','MyBlog');
```

Or

**Multiple Statement**

```
INSERT INTO EDITORS (Username,EName,Email,DOB,blogTitle)
VALUES ('john360','johnWest','jwest360@yahoo.co.uk','1980-08-23','MyGeneralBlog')

INSERT INTO EDITORS (Username,EName,Email,DOB,blogTitle)
 VALUES ('paul22344','paulWells','psmith@yahoo.co.uk','1960-09-20','PaulsBlog')

INSERT INTO EDITORS (Username,EName,Email,DOB,blogTitle)
 VALUES ('chrisB123','chrisBenson','cb360@hotmail.co.uk','1990-10-14','MyBlog')
```

[Source](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms174335.aspx&ei=a3xfVLr9OIaLuwSP6YDYCA&usg=AFQjCNHZjfaNRjbTcQSdusexatiIm054xw&sig2=cLki-LcvL_AkL0YJHdyjzw&bvm=bv.79189006,d.c2E)

Comment: You have a missing comma.

Answer (score 0):

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas.

```
INSERT INTO EDITORS (Username,EName,Email,DOB,blogTitle) VALUES
('john360','johnWest','jwest360@yahoo.co.uk','1980-08-23','MyGeneralBlog'),
('paul22344','paulWells','psmith@yahoo.co.uk','1960-09-20','PaulsBlog'),
('chrisB123','chrisBenson','cb360@hotmail.co.uk','1990-10-14','MyBlog');
```